# Canvas js chart not loading full width inside modal

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am trying to create a modal using javascript but when I am adding canvasjs chart inside that modal body width of canvas chart is not 100%.

You can see what I am seeing in this image:

[image]

I am using this code inside javascript:

```
     // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

I am using this code to initialise chart:

```
  let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  exportEnabled: true,
  title: {
    text: "Basic Column Chart in Angular"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: [
      { y: 71, label: "Apple" },
      { y: 55, label: "Mango" },
      { y: 50, label: "Orange" },
      { y: 65, label: "Banana" },
      { y: 95, label: "Pineapple" },
      { y: 68, label: "Pears" },
      { y: 28, label: "Grapes" },
      { y: 34, label: "Lychee" },
      { y: 14, label: "Jackfruit" }
    ]
  }]
});
chart.render();
```

I am trying to do this in javascript I don't know what do I need to do. I would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What I'm seeing in docs they have defined height and width in parent div and chart UI is respecting that dimensions, I suggest you to try this it will fix the problem 
https://canvasjs.com/

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I was saying that in their example they are handling width & height something like it

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>

Answer (score 3):

CanvasJS Chart automatically sets the width and height of the chart according to container’s dimensions. When the container’s dimension is not specified it takes up the default width & height(500px X 400px).

In bootstrap, the modal is not displayed initially, so chart takes the default width and height. To solve this issue, you should render the chart when the shown.bs.modal event is fired.

```
$('#chartModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    chart.render();
});
```

Please find the working code below:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
  title: {
    text: "Basic Column Chart"
  },
  data: [
    {
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55 },
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14 }
      ]
    }         
  ]
});

$('#chartModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  chart.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h4>CanvasJS Column Chart within Bootstrap Modal</h4>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" id="modalBtn"class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chartModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="chartModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">   
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">CanvasJS Chart within Bootstrap Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question is very simple you are loading your charts before your modal is visible you need to render chart when your modal is loaded.

In order to do this you need to put chart render inside your click event like this:

```
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Basic Column Chart in Angular"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
        { y: 71, label: "Apple" },
        { y: 55, label: "Mango" },
        { y: 50, label: "Orange" },
        { y: 65, label: "Banana" },
        { y: 95, label: "Pineapple" },
        { y: 68, label: "Pears" },
        { y: 28, label: "Grapes" },
        { y: 34, label: "Lychee" },
        { y: 14, label: "Jackfruit" }
        ]
    }]
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

This will solve your problem if you want to know why is this happening you can put this chart render before:

```
modal.style.display = "block";
```

You will see that your graph is not working properly. I hope this solves your problem.